# TCP Server - Multi User File Upload

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, design-patterns

I'm struggling with trying to figure out how to implement a TCP server in python. I currently have a TCP server that can connect to one client at a time. The Client can successfully communicate with the server, and upload a file using a single socket. Currently, it is single threaded and when one Client connects it blocks the other clients from connecting until it is done.

I'm struggling with the design portion on making this multi-client friendly. If I'm uploading files concurrently should there be multiple sockets? If I go with one socket, how do I differentiate data from different clients?

Can anyone give some advice on this?

Comment: You don't need multiple sockets but you do need multiple threads, or select(), or async I/O.

Comment: How do I differentiate between the data then on a single socket? Isn't it possible that two clients can be writing to a socket at the same time? I'm picturing something like this happening...

Client A sends "Apple"
Client B sends "Bananna"

Server reads AppBannlea

Comment: When a client connects to a listening socket, it splits off on the server end as a separate socket dedicated to that specific client connection. This new socket can be read from and written to totally independently of any other client socket.